# Corner radius for a particular corner

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I want to set corner radius to each corner separately, but in layer of the view I didn't find property or method for it, only for every corner. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this, I think it can be modified to achieve what you want since it rounds the borders using a CGPath: [UIView With Rounded Corners](http://www.warrenmoore.net/blog/2010/09/28/uiview-rounded-corners/)

You you could also do it by backing your UIView with a CAShapeLayer and setting the shape on that layer to a path created according to your corner specs.